# Query updates all rows in the table

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to update a single item's quantity in my database, but my query is updating all of the values in my quantity column.

How can this be fixed?

Here is my query:

```
UPDATE Stocks 
SET Stocks.Quantity = Stocks.Quantity - PointofSale.Quantity 
FROM PointofSale 
WHERE ItemID IN (SELECT ItemID FROM Recipe 
                 WHERE MenuID IN (SELECT MenuID FROM Menu 
                                  WHERE ItemName IN (SELECT Product FRPOM PointofSale 
                                                     WHERE POSID > 0)))
```

And below are some screenshots of my tables and DB layout.

This is my `Stocks` table:

[image]

This is the ID's that will call in my update query:

[image]

This is my Menu which contains all the products:

[image]

And this is my POS which has the column of quantity:

[image]

Comment: That is because there is absolutely no condition identifying **which** item/row from `Stocks` is meant to be updated. Bring `Stocks` to `from` clause and you will see that you are missing join predicate (you may see warning of the same name after running your query).

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 2):

(too long for comment)

piece of code from @Alex answer with my note from comment described:

```
UPDATE s SET 
  Quantity = Quantity - POS.Quantity
FROM Stocks s
INNER JOIN PointofSale AS POS
 ON ???
INNER JOIN Menu AS M
  ON M.ItemName = POS.Product
INNER JOIN Recipe AS R
  ON R.MenuID = M.MenuID
WHERE POS.POSID > 0
```

How is `Stocks` supposed to be joined to any of these tables? That is the cause of your troubles. Every row from `Stocks` "matches" all the rows from other tables because there is **no match condition** actually. This situation is called `MISSING JOIN PREDICATE`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this request:

```
UPDATE Stocks SET Stocks.Quantity = Stocks.Quantity - POS.Quantity
FROM PointofSale AS POS
INNER JOIN Menu AS M
  ON M.ItemName = POS.Product
INNER JOIN Recipe AS R
  ON R.MenuID = M.MenuID
WHERE POS.POSID > 0 AND Stocks.ItemID = R.ItemID
```

Comment: The statement is still missing join predicate to/from Stocks doesn't it? +1 for translating subqueries into joins

Comment: @IvanStarostin you're right. Corrected. Thanks for +1 and agreed with a lack of description.

Comment: It still affect all the rows '(89 row(s) affected)' it should affect base on the MenuID's and RecipeIDs

Comment: Now there is a scheme that works in such a way (roughly speaking): in your PointofSale name of product is taken. It is found in Menu table and an according MenuID is taken. Then in Recipes table **several** ItemIDs are taken according to one MenuID, all of them are affected in the Stocks table. This scheme repeates for all POSID > 0.

Comment: So, please, create another logical constraint (match condition) in this scheme as @IvanStarostin has proposed.

Comment: UPDATE s SET Quantity = s.Quantity - POS.Quantity FROM Stocks s INNER JOIN PointofSale AS POS ON s.ItemID = POS.POSID INNER JOIN Menu AS M ON M.ItemName = POS.Product INNER JOIN Recipe AS R ON R.MenuID = M.MenuID WHERE POS.POSID = Convert(varchar,POS.Product)          Ive tried my best and @IvanStarostin suggestion but now it results to Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'CHEESY JALAPENO STICKS' to data type int.

Comment: @MarkRimando Perhaps you need to join `Stocks` to `Recipe` by `ItemID`. But I can not know it for you.

Comment: @MarkRimando could you show us a single item's quantity that you'd like to be updated? Your `Stocks` contains products but `PointofSale` is a dish table, isn't it? 1 item in `POS` should thus affect not single but several items in `Stocks`.

Comment: And furthermore, it is incorrect to use `Stocks.Quantity = Stocks.Quantity - PointofSale.Quantity` because Stocks is a components table and PointofSale is a dishes table.